# How to get channel's active members' count with Telegram API?

Tags: php, telegram

I want to get a channel's active members' count but I don't know which method should I use?

Comment: There is certainly an API page on their website.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog)

> Bot API 2.1. Added more tools for group administrator bots. Your bot can now get a list of administrators and members count in a group,